# Module not found: Can't resolve '@material/core/Grid'

Tags: html, npm, material-ui

I cloned a repository that uses MUI and the following components are already imported when I cloned (they work)

```
import Card from '@mui/material/Card'
import CardActions from '@mui/material/CardActions'
import CardContent from '@mui/material/CardContent'
import CardMedia from '@mui/material/CardMedia'
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography'
```

then I tried to `import Grid from '@material/core/Grid'` but got the error `Module not found: Can't resolve '@material/core/Grid'` even though I ran the following commands both in the repository folder as well as "/Downloads":

```
npm install @material-ui/core
npm install
npm install @material-ui/core/Grid
```

I can provide more info if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see how all the working components are `@mui/material/SOMETHING`?

Also see [the documentation for Grid](https://mui.com/api/grid/).

It's `import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';` not `from '@material/core/Grid'`.